# Identifying identical pairs across two tables

Tags: sql, compare

I have two tables that has the same data. It is collected over two weeks. For example

In table 1 you have

```
IP|Zip|state
x.x.x.x|abcde|NJ
y.y.y.y|qwert|NY
z.z.z.z|werty|NH
```

In table 2 you have

```
IP|Zip|state
x.x.x.x|abcde|NJ
y.y.y.y|qwert|NY
m.m.m.m|werty|NH
z.z.z.z|merty|CA
```

I am looking to overlap these tables and compare of IP:Zip pairs and then count number of IPs changed zip by state of table 1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your expected result for this data? 1 (z.z.z.z) or 2 (z.z.z.z and m.m.m.m)?

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, ...?

Comment: NJ - 0, NY -0, NH-1 (because z.z.z.z changed the zip)

Comment: @avogadro . . . Show the results that you want.  I don't really see how the state can change if the zip does not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I am looking to see how IPs move around and so in this case NJ -0  bcoz x.x.x.x did not change zip but with NH - z.z.z.z changed zip and so count is incremented to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a `join` and aggregation:

```
select t1.state, count(t2.ip)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ip = t2.ip and t1.state = t2.state and t1.zip <> t2.zip
group by t1.state;
```